# Read data from large tar.gz file from the website

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, urllib2, tar

1) How should I read the data from all the csv files in the tar.gz file on website and write them to the CSVs on a folder in the most memory and space efficient way? 
2) How can I loop it to go over all the CSVs in the tar.gz file?
3) Since the CSV files are huge, how can I loop it to read and write, let's say, 1 million rows at a time?

I have gone only so far using the codes on other stackoverflow answers!

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib2
import tarfile
url='https://ghtstorage.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/mysql-2016-08-01.tar.gz'
r=urllib2.Request(url)
o=urllib2.urlopen(r)

thetarfile=tarfile.open(o, mode='r:gz')
thetarfile.close()
```

Comment: You can't work with a remote file without downloading it. You can avoid writing it to disk though, if that's what you mean. Similarly, you can't work with files inside a tgz without unzipping them. And why avoid downloading and unzipping if you're going to write the csv files to a folder anyway?

Comment: Thanks, Rawing! Now, how can I avoid writing it to the disk and write the csv files. Based on your feedback, I have updated my question. I can surely use your help, here.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download an archive to your local storage.
2. Display the list of files in the archive. Run **man tar** to see options for command line.
3. Extract files one by one from the archive.
4. Use SAX xml parser https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.reader.html.
5. Remove file after parsing.
6. Remove the archive.